# How to create dynamic responsive card view using serverside data in bootstap 4?

Tags: java, jquery, bootstrap-4

I want to create a card view which dynamically generate from loop. But card view is generated vertically. I want 3 column in row .But when i run, it  generates vertical cardview. Actually my data come from server. Here is my card view  image look like..

[image]

I have used bellow like to create card view. It create a card view vertically. that means single row

```
<% for (User_Model model : list) {%>       
                 <div class="row">
                         <div class="col-sm-4">                
                             <div class="card" >                                     
                                 <div class="card-body">
                                     <h5 class="card-title">Card Title</h5>
                                     <p class="card-text"> Text</p>
                                 </div>                                    
                             </div>                
                         </div>                        

                     </div>
        <% }%>
```

**My above Loop is given data like**

```
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {      
 }
```

Please Help me to create  horizontal card view above code..

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Output will be like.
https://www.screencast.com/t/vvcIZU1Mv

```
<%! int loop_counter =1; int innerBreak = 1;%>
    <% for (User_Model model : list) {     

    if(innerBreak == 1){ %>
    <!-- when complete 3 column in a row open new-->
    <div class="row">
    <% } %>
             <div class="col-sm-4">                
                 <div class="card" >                                     
                     <div class="card-body">
                         <h5 class="card-title">Card Title</h5>
                         <p class="card-text"> Text</p>
                     </div>                                    
                 </div>                
             </div>                        

    <!-- when complete 3 column in a row closed previous open div -->
    <%if(loop_counter%3==0){%>
    </div>
    <% innerBreak = 1;}else{ innerBreak = 0;}

    loop_counter++;

    }%>
```